# Running a basic docker container on Google Cloud with terraform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-artifact-registry

I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer to this anywhere, and the more I try to understand this the more confusing it becomes. Essentially, I have a 'hello world' node app in a Docker container that I want to upload and run on Google Cloud via Terraform. However, I can't seem to find a straight forward example of this being done that works. I've been able to do it via Google's GUI, but I can't find the right commands in terraform. How do I do this?

Comment: Everything you do in the GUI should be able to be done via Terraform. Have you looked at the Google Terraform Registry (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs)? A step-by-step of what you are doing in GCP console would help to help you out.

Comment: @Romain I'm following it right now (https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling). But I can't find what pieces of terraform code correspond with these steps. For example, I can't find anything equivalent to the docker push part.

Comment: It's expected. The GCP provider will only help you to create the repo through TF but not the push because is not something about GCP but about container registries in general. You may need to create for example a `local-exec` to execute the docker/podman push for that.